# Python changing part of a file name

Tags: python, recursion

Hi I have a number of different files that need to be renamed to something else. I got this far but I want to have it so that I can have many items to replace and their corresponding replacements rather than type each one out, run the code then retype it again. Also I need the rename to only change part of the file not the whole thing so if there was a "Cat5e_1mBend1bottom50m2mBend2top-Aqeoiu31" it would just change it to "'Cat5e50m1mBED_50m2mBE2U-Aqeoiu31
Running python 2.5

```
import os, glob

name_map = {
     "Cat5e_1mBend1bottom50m2mBend2top": 'Cat5e50m1mBED_50m2mBE2U'
}

#searches for roots, directory and files
for root,dirs,files in os.walk(r"H:\My Documents\CrossTalk"):
   for f in files:
       if f in name_map:
          try:
             os.rename(os.path.join(root, f), os.path.join(root, name_map[f]))
          except FileNotFoundError, e:
          #except FileNotFoundError as e:  # python 3
             print(str(e))
```

Comment: Do you have a rule that can be used to recognized the files to be renamed, or a list of such file names? Do you have another rule that explains how to convert an old name to the new name?

Comment: you have to loop through the `name_map` for each file and search for a substring in the filename (eg. `for pattern, ren_to in name_map.items(): if pattern in f: os.rename(...)`

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko that will change only part of the string? Can you post the solution if you have it because I'm not quite following you

Comment: @DYZ no I don't, and I don't know how to go about it tbh

Comment: You will need to have some kind of pattern or at least a manually typed out list of the names. Once you have that you can just do `if pattern in file_name: change the name to this` in your loop.

Comment: @Posh_Pumpkin really? Its a simple name replace though, this sounds like machine learning

Comment: @VisualExstasy Yes, I'm talking about a simple name replace. If you have three files - `A1C`, `A2C`, `ABC` - then you can do `for file in files: if file[1].isdigit(): os.rename(file, new_name)`. Obviously, depending on the complexity of the pattern the task could become extremely difficult. But if you wanted your computer to implicitly know what pattern to apply like a human, then *that* would be ML, not my example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out by Hector, the easiest way to accomplish this task is to use regular expressions. Luckily Python has an excellent regular expressions module called `re`. Essentially we are looking to see if any of the patterns we have specified in the `name_map` match the current file we are looking at. If the pattern does match, ONLY the matching part is subbed out, and then is renamed.

```
import os, glob, re

name_map = {
    "bad": "good",
    "cat": "dog"
}

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(r"/Users/.../start/"):
    for f in files:
        for name in name_map.keys():
            if re.search(name,f) != None:
                new_name = re.sub(name,name_map[name],f)
                try:
                    os.rename(os.path.join(root,f), os.path.join(root, new_name))
                except OSError:
                    print "No such file or directory!"
```

So given some directory `start` with the contents:
    `bad_name.txt`
    `catdogcat.csv`

This will script will rename them to:
    `good_name.txt`
    `dogdogdog.csv`

The two main takeaways from this should be how to use the `re.search()` and `re.sub()` methods. `re.search(pattern, string)` looks for the pattern in the provided string. If it finds it, it will return a `Match` object and if it does not then it will instead return `None`. This makes testing for a pattern in a string a breeze. Once we have found that the pattern exists, the next step is to replace it with our new name. Enter the `re.sub()` method. `re.sub(pattern, replace, string)` searches for a pattern in the provided string and then replaces that pattern with the contents of replace.

I highly encourage you to look at [the docs for the `re` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) as it is quite powerful and can be used to solve a number of problems.

Answer (score 1):

Something like that?

```
files = ['something', 'nothing', 'no_really_not',
         'something_something', 'nothing_to_replace']
name_map = {'nothing': 'something',
            'something': 'nothing'}

for f in files:
    for pat, rep  in name_map.iteritems():
        if f.find(pat) >= 0:
            f_new = f.replace(pat, rep)
            print('Rename {} -> {}'.format(f, f_new))
            break
    else:
        print('Keep {}'.format(f))
```

That is pretty pedestrian. Not good if multiple replacements for one file should be honored ...

Comment: how does this sort through my directories though?

Comment: You didn't seem to have a problem with the `os.walk` part or the actual renaming. So I left that out for clarity.

Comment: if you don't mind can you explain it to me step by step. I just want extra clarity

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely look into [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/re.html).

If you have a pattern definition of what you need to change and the replacement, it's really simple using [re.sub](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/re.html#re.sub)

Comment: Can't figure it out